# g++ compiler : unable to compile

Tags: c++, g++, cygwin

This is the first time that I'm using the g++ compiler to compile my c++ programs. I have installed cygwin g++. and I'm trying to run a very simple program to display "hello", to see wether it would work.

The problem is that whatever path that I type in I get the error:

```
*-bash: cd: c:program: No such file or directory*
```

The path I typed in is

```
*$ cd c:\program files\internet explorer*
```

Thats where I installed cygwin into.  But for some reason it's not working the way it should. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: I recommend you install cygwin to C:\Cygwin (or some other directory without spaces). See http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#pathnames-win32 for information about Windows paths

Comment: Instead, if you don't actually need a POSIX compatibility layer, I recommend you to get a native Windows compiler instead of using CygWin (MinGW or VC++ are the most used).

Comment: its working now...:) .....thank u all for ur help......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add some " around your path, as it contains spaces :

```
cd "c:\Program files\internet explorer"
```

my2c

Comment: but now,when i give

Comment: $ g++ hello.cpp-o main
i get the error                                                            g++: hello.cpp-o: No such file or directory
g++: main: No such file or directory
g++: no input files

Comment: You forgot a space between `hello.cpp` and `-o`.

Comment: i used space..... but i got the same error

Comment: try g++ hello.cpp -o test.exe

Comment: i tried but.....same error

Comment: You're sure the hello.cpp is in the current directory? And I'm not sure, but could the file names be case sensitive? (Can't check here, no cygwin)

Comment: @amrithta: Edit your question (this is the SO way of doing things) and type your exact commands ...

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with GCC or the g++ compiler. The problem is that the command prompt thinks that *c:\program files\internet explorer* is actually three arguments: "c:\program", "files\internet" and "explorer". You need to put it in quotes like this *"c:\program files\internet explorer"*.

Answer (score 2):

You have a space in your path ...

```
cd "c:\program files\internet explorer"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only tangentially C++, but `cd "c:\program files\internet explorer"`.

Answer (score 0):

`bash` uses backslashes as escapes, similar to C string literals. Try `cd '/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Internet Explorer'` since bash also doesn't quite understand drive letters, and will consider the spaces as argument separators without the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

CygWin is a POSIX emulation layer, thus CygWin programs use POSIX-like paths, which do not have the concept of drive letters, but everything is under the `/` hierarchy. Long story short, to access Windows paths you have to refer to the path hierarchy under `/cygdrive/`. (see [CygWin documentation](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames))

Your `c:\Program files\Internet Explorer` will become `/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Internet Explorer` (naturally you'll have to add quotes, otherwise bash will interpret the space as an argument separator).

***Edit***: apparently the `cd` command does this mapping by itself; still, it's a thing to keep in mind that CygWin programs will actually see the POSIX path, not the Windows path.

On the other hand, I don't see why you should be using CygWin if you are only programming in standard C++: probably you don't need a POSIX emulation layer, but a native C++ compiler for Windows. You can use for example MinGW (the Windows port of gcc) or Visual C++ (whose Express Edition is available for free).